# Beeping iPad connects to iTunes in VMWare's Windows 10 but not in macOS

Tags: macos, itunes, ipad, vmware

I like to connect my iPad (3rd Gen; Wi-Fi + Cellular) to iTunes in my macOS (10.12.5) using the USB cable. This fails but the funny thing is that it works fine when I enable the USB connection to be forwarded to my Windows 10 running on the same machine under VMWare Fusion (8.5.8). This rules out any hardware problem I think. It syncs and backups fine under VMWare.

The [image: Console messages for iTunes]
come up every ~0.5 second in sync with the beeping of the iPad. They read:

```
> Assertion failure: error == noErr (-402653052) 
> failed to connect to USB device 0x6100003940f0, UDID 340a25595bfa87ccb0d4fd3f7bee6c5ea4470d80 (0xE8000084)
```

The System Information lists the iPad as present under the USB 3.0 Bus.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

FIX: from: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5523411?start=0&tstart=0

"""tap Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy. This will also reset your location and privacy settings. You can also untrust all computers by tapping Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings on the ipad/iphone"""

I guess the last part is what fixed my problem as on macOS the question came up if I wanted to trust this computer. After that it worked again. I hope this helps other people looking for a similar problem.